# What does whether or not the hit icon is filled mean?

Tags: guns-of-icarus-online

When you hit someone, a little icon pops up to indicate it. Sometimes it's filled in though, and sometimes it isn't.

[image]

What does that signify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- A filled hit icon means you are the one that made the hit.
- A non-filled hit icon means another player/AI on your airship made the hit.